# Lower bound on the difference between max. and min. values of a polynomial over $[-1, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials, functional-inequalities

**Problem:** Let $P(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $n$ with real coefficients. Prove that it is not possible that for all $t \in [-1, 1]$, $$\frac{-1}{2^n} < P(t) < \frac{1}{2^n}.$$

I tried it to put it in another way: If $P(a)$ and $P(b)$ are the maximum and minimum respectively of $P$ on $[-1, 1]$, then show that $$P(a)-P(b) > \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}.$$

But I am completely stuck.

Comment: sorry I took monic as monotone.

Comment: For some direction, you can try working with (monic) Chebyshev polynomials